# How can I go from a Wai Request to a Yesod Route?

Tags: haskell, basic-authentication, yesod, haskell-wai

I'd like to use the [Wai HttpAuth Middleware](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-HttpAuth.html) to hide a few pages behind HTTP basic auth. For this the HttpAuth middleware provides `authIsProtected :: !(Request -> IO Bool)`.

To implement `authIsProtected` I need to check if the URL is admin-only; it seems like the best way to do that is to create [route attributes](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/route-attributes) in the `routes` file, then access them using this function: `routeAttrs :: RouteAttrs a => Route a -> Set Text`.

However, I don't have access to a `Route` in the `authIsProtected` function, just a Wai `Request`. Is there a way I can go from a Wai `Request` to a `Route`? I figure Yesod must do this under the hood but I couldn't figure out where/how.

Its possible I should be doing the authentication in `isAuthorized` instead, where I have access to the `Route`, but I'm not sure I can run the HTTP basic auth from there.

```
makeApplication :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra -> IO Application
makeApplication conf = do
    foundation <- makeFoundation conf

    app <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ basicAuth 
                (\u p -> return $ u == "username" && p == "password") 
                ("My Realm" { authIsProtected = \waiRequest -> do 
                    -- Would like to access a route / route attrs here
                    return True } :: AuthSettings) 
                $ app
```

Edit: Here's what I came up with:

```
import Network.Wai (queryString, pathInfo, Request)
import Network.HTTP.Types.URI (queryToQueryText)
import Control.Arrow (second)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Yesod (Route)
import Data.Set (member)

makeApplication :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra -> IO Application
makeApplication conf = do
    foundation <- makeFoundation conf

    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    app <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ basicAuth 
                (\u p -> return $ u == "username" && p == "password") 
                ("My Realm" { authIsProtected = \waiReq -> do 
                    let mRoute = parseRoute(pathInfo waiReq,textQueryString waiReq) :: Maybe (Route App)
                    return $ maybe False adminOnly mRoute
                    } :: AuthSettings) 
                $ app

adminOnly :: Route App -> Bool
adminOnly r = "admin" `member` routeAttrs r

-- Copied from Yesod.Core.Internal.Request
textQueryString :: Request -> [(Text, Text)]
textQueryString = map (second $ fromMaybe "") . queryToQueryText . queryString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [parseRoute](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v:parseRoute) provide you what you're looking for? You just need to team it up with [pathInfo](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/wai/Network-Wai.html#v:pathInfo) and [queryString](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/wai/Network-Wai.html#v:queryString).

Comment: Yeah that's what I needed! I found `parseRoute` but couldn't figure out what arguments it was meant to take. I edited my question with the code I came up with, which seems to work nicely.