# How to add basic auth to Scotty middleware?

Tags: authentication, haskell, functional-programming, middleware, scotty

I'm currently making a Scotty API and I couldn't find any examples of basicAuth implementations (Wai Middleware HttpAuth).

Specifically, I want to add basic auth headers (user, pass) to SOME of my endpoints (namely, ones that start with "admin"). I have everything set up, but I can't seem to make the differentiation as to which endpoints require auth and which ones don't. I know I need to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198149/how-can-i-go-from-a-wai-request-to-a-yesod-route), but it uses Yesod, and I wasn't able to translate it to Scotty.

So far, I have this:

```
routes :: (App r m) => ScottyT LText m ()
routes = do
  -- middlewares
  middleware $ cors $ const $ Just simpleCorsResourcePolicy
    { corsRequestHeaders = ["Authorization", "Content-Type"]
    , corsMethods = "PUT":"DELETE":simpleMethods
    }
    
  middleware $ basicAuth 
      (\u p -> return $ u == "username" && p == "password") 
      "My Realm" 
  
  -- errors
  defaultHandler $ \str -> do
    status status500
    json str

  -- feature routes
  ItemController.routes
  ItemController.adminRoutes
  
  -- health
  get "/api/health" $
    json True
```

But it adds authentication to all my requests. I only need it in some of them.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `authIsProtected` field of the `AuthSettings` to define a function `Request -> IO Bool` that determines if a particular (Wai) `Request` is subject to authorization by basic authentication.  In particular, you can inspect the URL path components and make a determination that way.

Unfortunately, this means that the check for authorization is completely separated from the Scotty routing.  This works fine in your case but can make fine-grained control of authorization by Scotty route difficult.

Anyway, the `AuthSettings` are the overloaded `"My Realm"` string in your source, and according to the documentation, the recommended way of defining the settings is to use the overloaded string to write something like:

```
authSettings :: AuthSettings
authSettings = "My Realm" { authIsProtected = needsAuth }
```

That looks pretty horrible, but anyway, the `needsAuth` function will have signature:

```
needsAuth :: Request -> IO Bool
```

so it can inspect the Wai `Request` and render a decision in IO on whether or not the page needs basic authentication first.  Calling `pathInfo` on the `Request` gives you a list of path components (no hostname and no query parameters).  So, for your needs, the following should work:

```
needsAuth req = return $ case pathInfo req of
  "admin":_ -> True   -- all admin pages need authentication
  _         -> False  -- everything else is public
```

Note that these are the parsed non-query path components, so `/admin` and `/admin/` and `/admin/whatever` and even `/admin/?q=hello` are protected, but obviously `/administrator/...` is not.

A full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.HttpAuth
import Data.Text ()   -- needed for "admin" overloaded string in case
import Network.Wai (Request, pathInfo)

authSettings :: AuthSettings
authSettings = "My Realm" { authIsProtected = needsAuth }

needsAuth :: Request -> IO Bool
needsAuth req = return $ case pathInfo req of
  "admin":_ -> True   -- all admin pages need authentication
  _         -> False  -- everything else is public

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware $ basicAuth (\u p -> return $ u == "username" && p == "password") authSettings
  get "/admin/deletedb" $ do
    html "<h1>Password database erased!</h1>"
  get "/" $ do
    html "<h1>Homepage</h1><p>Please don't <a href=/admin/deletedb>Delete the passwords</a>"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was super clear, and worked perfectly :)