# How to insert array using postgresql simple (Haskell)?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, scotty

I am working on a Haskell API using Scotty and PostgreSQL-simple. I cannot figure out how to do an insert of a column containing an Array of Text. So far my queries have worked, but something about this one does not seem to compile well.

This is what I have:

```
addOrder :: Postgres r m => OrderIntent -> m ()
addOrder param =
  void . withConn $ \conn -> execute conn qry (orderIntentTable param, orderIntentItemsSlug param)
  where
    qry = "insert into orders (table, items, created_at, updated_at) values (?, ?, now(), now())"
```

My OrderIntent and its FromRow are:

```
data OrderIntent = OrderIntent
{ orderIntentTable :: Integer
, orderIntentItemsSlug :: [Text] 
} deriving(Eq, Show)

instance FromRow OrderIntent where
  fromRow = OrderIntent 
    <$> field
    <*> (fromPGArray <$> field)
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
• Could not deduce (Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField.ToField
                          [Data.Text.Internal.Text])
        arising from a use of ‘execute’
      from the context: Postgres r m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   addOrder :: forall r (m :: * -> *).
                               Postgres r m =>
                               OrderIntent -> m ()
        at Core/Order/DAO.hs:11:1-47
```

I could not figure out how to use the PostgreSQL library to parse an Array of Text so that i can be inserted to the database. If any of you could help me I would really appreciate it!

PS: I also have [this other blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948172/how-to-add-basic-auth-to-scotty-middleware) from a couple of days ago, if you happen to know about Scotty auth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`PGArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.4/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Types.html#t:PGArray).

```
execute conn qry (orderIntentTable param, PGArray (orderIntentItemsSlug param))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you're inserting `orderIntentItemsSlug`s, you need a `ToField` instance for `orderIntentItemsSlug` (which is a `[Text]`).
This is what your error tells you.

I recommend looking at the sources of other [`ToField` instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.4/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToField.html#v:toField) to figure out how you want to do that (one hacky way would be to turn your field into a `Text` first, which already gas a `ToField` instance).

You could also write an orders table that relates an `orderID` to one item at a time, then you wouldn't have to write any instances at all.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm not sure what you mean by turning my field into a Text first. Could you explain a bit more? In my case I just need to insert an array such as ["a", "b", "c"] into the column "items"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66030065/6522680 for a better solution. You have a `[Text]`, which can't be inserted. You can turn a `[Text]` into a `Text` with `T.pack . show`, for example.